# How to compile and simulate a modelica model that is part of a package with JModelica?

Tags: package, modelica, openmodelica

My question is similar to the [question of janpeter](http://www.jmodelica.org/4142). I study the [ebook by Tiller](http://book.xogeny.com/) and try to simulate the [example 'Architecture Driven Approach'](http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/sensor_comparison_ad/) with [OpenModelica](http://openmodelica.org) and [JModelica](http://jmodelica.org). I tried the minimal example 'BaseSystem' in OpenModelica and it works fine. But with JModelica version 1.14 I get errors in the compiling process and my script fail. My python script is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pymodelica import compile_fmu
from pyfmi import load_fmu

# Variables: modelName, modelFile, extraLibPath
modelName = 'BaseSystem'
modelFile = 'BaseSystem.mo'
extraLibPath = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a\ModelicaByExample\Architectures'
compilerOption = {'extra_lib_dirs':[extraLibPath]}

# Compile model
fmuName = compile_fmu( modelName, modelFile, compiler_options=compilerOption)

# Load model
model = load_fmu( fmuName)

# Simulate model
res = model.simulate( start_time=0.0, final_time=5.0)

# Extract interesting values
res_w = res['sensor.w']
res_y = res['setpoint.y']
tSim = res['time']

# Visualize results
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(tSim, res_w, 'g-')
ax2.plot(tSim, res_y, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('t (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('w (???)', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('y (???)', color='b')
plt.title('BaseSystem')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

My problem is how to compile and simulate a model that is part of a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Michael Tiller. With your support I found the solution.

First, the `modelName` has to be full qualified. Second, as you mentioned, the `extraLibPath` should end at the top-level directory of the library *ModelicaByExample*. But then I got errors, that JModelica couldn't find components or declarations which are part of the *Modelica Standard Library (MSL)*.

So I added the `modelicaLibPath` to the MSL, but the error messages remained the same. After many attempts, I launched the command line with administrator privileges and any errors were gone.

Here is the executable python script: *BaseSystem.py*

```html
###  Attention!
# The script and/or the command line must be
# started with administrator privileges

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pymodelica import compile_fmu
from pyfmi import load_fmu

# Variables: modelName, modelFile, extraLibPath
modelName = 'Architectures.SensorComparison.Examples.BaseSystem'
modelFile = ''
extraLibPath = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a\ModelicaByExample'
modelicaLibPath = 'C:\OpenModelica1.9.2\lib\omlibrary\Modelica 3.2.1'
compileToPath = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a'

# Set the compiler options
compilerOptions = {'extra_lib_dirs':[modelicaLibPath, extraLibPath]}

# Compile model
fmuName = compile_fmu( modelName, modelFile, compiler_options=compilerOptions, compile_to=compileToPath)

# Load model
model = load_fmu( fmuName)

# Simulate model
res = model.simulate( start_time=0.0, final_time=5.0)

# Extract interesting values
res_w = res['sensor.w']
res_y = res['setpoint.y']
tSim = res['time']

# Visualize results
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(tSim, res_w, 'g-')
ax2.plot(tSim, res_y, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('t (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('sensor.w (rad/s)', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('setpoint.y (rad/s)', color='b')
plt.title('BaseSystem')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a jModelica user, but I think I see some confusion in your script.  You wrote:

```
modelName = 'BaseSystem'
modelFile = 'BaseSystem.mo'
extraLibPath = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a\ModelicaByExample\Architectures'
```

But that implies (to me) that the compiler should open the package stored at `C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a\ModelicaByExample\Architectures`.  But the top-level package is `ModelicaByExample` and the model you want is `Architectures.BaseSystem`.  So I think something like this is probably more appropriate:

```
modelName = 'Architectures.BaseSystem'
modelFile = 'package.mo'
extraLibPath = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tiller2015a\ModelicaByExample'
```

The essential point here is that you should be opening `ModelicaByExample` (specifically, the `package.mo` file in the `ModelicaByExample` directory).  That opens the `ModelicaByExample` package.  You need to open this package because it is the top-level package.  You can't load just a sub-package (which is what it looked like you were trying to do).  Then, once you've got `ModelicaByExample` loaded, you can ask the compiler to specifically compile `Architectures.BaseSystem`.

I suspect OpenModelica was "helping" you by opening the top-level package anyway, even if you were asking it to open the sub-package.

But again, I don't know jModelica very well and I have definitely not tested any of these suggestions.